# NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest response is nil upon invalid credential

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I'm getting a weird behavior where using `sendSynchronousRequest` or `sendAsynchronousRequest` with invalid credential will make the nsurlresponse nil. But the old way with the `[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];` I get the 401 response code.

The error value using the  `sendSynchronousRequest` or `sendAsynchronousRequest` is

> `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x756ecb0
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=myurl,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=myurl,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x75704d0 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"`

Does someone have a clue as to why it is like that? Any information on this is appreciated. I was expecting to get a 401 response from  `sendSynchronousRequest` or `sendAsynchronousRequest`

Thanks,

Comment: Do check that `error:` argument...

Answer (score 4):

This error is caused when a `WWW-Authenticate:` HTTP header is returned with the 401 response, asking for user-interaction to enter valid credentials. The `NSURLConnection` processes the HTTP headers and the response body, returning the response data correctly as an `NSData` object, but leaving the `returningResponse` object as `nil`.

According to Apple's [Foundation Constants Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW40), the error -1012 is:

> `NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication`
>
> Returned when an asynchronous request for authentication is cancelled by the user.
>
> This is typically incurred by clicking a “Cancel” button in a username/password dialog, rather than the user making an attempt to
>   authenticate.

I am speculating that it automatically treats the `WWW-Authenticate:` header as a request for credentials that was cancelled by the user (since it is [headless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_computer)) and generates the error. Then some other part of the code-path that should set the response is not executed because there was an error. Personally I think this is either a bug or bad design. It should be ok to get a valid HTTP response and an error at the same time, either way, you get a valid HTTP response so the `returningResponse` should be set. Bad Apple!

Comment: Yup, very bad Apple.  I can't believe this bug in sendSynchronousRequest is still alive and kicking in 2015.

Comment: So WTF is the solution?

Comment: To work around it, you will need to make sure you send valid authenticate headers whenever you connect to a service that requires it, this means you should not see this problem. The only real "solution" is to either wait for Apple to fix the bug, or use something other than `NSURLConnection` for this type of request.

Comment: but we can put a check against -1012 error code to server as 401?